# REGEX-String and escaped quote

Tags: python, regex

How to get what is between the quotes in the following two texts ?

```
text_1 = r""" "Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\" \
     + "Another text on \"three\" lines" """

text_2 = r""" "Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\" + "Another text on \"three\" lines" """
```

The problem for me is that the quotes should be ignored if they are escaped, but there is the possibilty to have the backslash escaped.

I would like to obtain the following groups.

```
[
    r'Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\',
    r'Another text on \"three\" lines'
]
```

Comment: Sorry I've edited my question because some spurious spaces have been added by the google translator.

Comment: You'll need more escapes there. Why the concatenation in the middle? That just distracts from your question

Comment: I've also forgotten the escaped quotes, that has been done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your're right. Here is now the simpler version of my uqestion.

Comment: There is nothing to ignore? I don't see any escaped

Comment: Is this a good example? `text = "Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\" \
     + "Another text on \"three\" lines \\\"four\\\""`

Comment: Sorry, here is a better example.

Comment: @projetmbc In your new example, every quote is escape, so does that mean you ignore all of them? Anyway, I updated my answer to produce your result

Comment: You're right. I've forgotten the escaped backslash.

Comment: @projetmbc I've changed it for the updated example, It's still kinda unclear what you need though, please comment and tell me if it doesn't  work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"
```

matches a quoted string, including any escaped characters that occur within it.

**Explanation:**

```
"       # Match a quote.
(?:     # Either match...
 \\.    # an escaped character
|       # or
 [^"\\] # any character except quote or backslash.
)*      # Repeat any number of times.
"       # Match another quote.
```

Comment: This gives me `unexpected end of regular expression` error. Any ideas why?

Comment: @SaheelGodhane: Most probably because of string processing. In Python, you'd need a raw string in single quotes if you want to compile this regex: `re.compile(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Some text on\n\"two\"lines" + "Another texton\n\"three\"\nlines"
>>> re.findall(r'"(.*)"', text)
["two", "three"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten some escaped quotes in my question. This has been updated.

Comment: That doesn't matter, as far as I can tell. EDIT: Well, it does. Let me look into it.

Comment: `.*` will consume all symbols including `"`, so if it wasn't for a new line `\n`, it would output `"two\"linesAnother texton\"three\"`

Comment: @projetmbc Glad to hear that, still perreal gave you the correct answer. Be sure to accept it, if it fits your needs!

Comment: @Pit Inded there is a porbleme if something like `"..." + "..."` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Match everything but a double quote:

```
import re
text = "Some text on \"two\" lines" + "Another text on \"three\" lines"
print re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', text)
```

**Output**

```
['two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> text_1 = r""" "Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\" \
     + "Another text on \"three\" lines" """
>>> text_2 = r""" "Some text on \"two\" lines with a backslash escaped\\" + "Another text on \"three\" lines" """
>>> re.findall(r'\\"([^"]+)\\"', text_2)
['two', 'three']
>>> re.findall(r'\\"([^"]+)\\"', text_1)
['two', 'three']
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
re.findall(r'\\"((?:(?<!\\)[^"])+)\\"', text)
```

Comment: Sorry for the poorness of my english because it is ont my native language. So I would "simply" like to catch Python strings for highlighting them and for other stufs.

Comment: @projetmbc That's fine, you could provide an example this doesn't work for?

Comment: I've added the groups I would like to obtain.

Comment: @projetmbc alright well it's good that someone understands this!

Comment: No so easy to be understandable with another language that his native one. Sorry.

Comment: @projetmbc Oh what I meant was I tried his solution and it produced different results to what you asked for. Anyway let's forget about this now!