# Python Regex get everything within parentheses unless in quotes

Tags: python, regex

Given the string

```
S = "(45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600),(43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600),(45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699)"
```

I'd like to extract everything within the parentheses UNLESS the parens are inside a quotation. So far I've managed to get everything within parentheses, but I can't figure out how to stop from splitting on the inner parenthesis inside the quotes.
My current code is:

```
import re
S = "(45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600),(43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600),(45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699)"

p = re.compile( "\((.*?)\)" )
m =p.findall(S)
for element in m:
    print element
```

What I want is:

```
45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600
43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600
45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699
```

What I currently get is:

```
45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600
43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation
45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation
```

What can I do in order to ignore the internal paren?

Thank you!!

---

In case it helps, here are the threads I've looked at:

1) [REGEX-String and escaped quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130404/regex-string-and-escaped-quote)

2) [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

3)[Get the string within brackets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569201/get-the-string-within-brackets-in-python-using-regex)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a non-capturing group to assert either a comma or the end of the string follows:

```
p = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)(?:,|$)')
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/315454)

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in S[1:-1].split('),('):
    print element
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600),(43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600),(45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699)"
>>> for i in re.findall(r"\(((?:'[^']*'|[^()])*)\)", s):
        print(i)


45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600
43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600
45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` - Matches a literal ( symbol.
- `(`  - Start of a capturing group.
- `(?:'[^']*'|[^()])*` - '[^']*' part matches greedily the  single quoted block. If there is any `(`, `)` symbols present inside that, it won't care about that. Because we used `[^']*` which matches any character but not of `'` , zero or more times. If the following character is not the start of a single quoted block then the control transfers to the pattern which exists next to the `|` symbol ie, `[^()]` which matches any character but not of `(` or `)`. So the whole `(?:'[^']*'|[^()])*` will match a single quoted block or any char not of `(`, `)` , zero or more times.
- `)` end of the capturing group.
- `\)` literal ) symbol.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vO4mB4/1)

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful and general enough all different string permutations.

Comment: @MayaR [Accept an answer which you loves the most](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some simple approach would be [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) - check that after closing brace no quote follows, e.g.

```
import re
S = "(45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600),(43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600),(45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699)"

m = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)(?![\'])', S)
for element in m:
    print element
```

prints

```
45171924,-1,'AbuseFilter/658',2600
43795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2600
45795362,-1,'!!_(disambiguation)',2699
```

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_CL89xhroV0_0.py

I have put the quote in character class (square brackets), so that you could add other symbols, which should make the closing bracket being ignored.